# Unable to determine randomness vs code issue

Tags: c#, random, do-while

I'm unable to tell if there is something wrong with Random number generator in this case.

```
Random x = new Random();
do
{
    a = x.Next(1, 200);
    aa = x.Next(1, 200);
    b = x.Next(a + 1, 200);
    bb = x.Next(aa + 1, 200);
    Console.WriteLine(a + " " + aa + "     " + b + " " + bb);

} while (a != aa || b != bb);
```

I'm comparing when two pairs of random numbers are the same, when they are I want to know what those numbers are. For some reason they always end up being in range of 150 - 200. Which doesn't seem random enough to me.

Basically I'm trying simulate how long it would take until 2 number lottery is won.

Is this because Random class is not random enough or is there problem with the code?

Comment: I am confused... What is in range of 150-200? It seems to me all 4 of those values will always be in 1-56 range.

Comment: Adding to @liho1eye, are you adding the four numbers when you say 150 to 200?

Comment: I had it set to max value 200 previously, just changed it in the code.

Comment: I am also confused as to why you have two pairs... And the second pair (`b`-`bb`) is of course more likely to end up with a match since it will always work on a smaller range.

Comment: Is [this](http://ideone.com/C90tQ) what you are expecting? If not, why not?

Comment: The b and bb is made with +1 so that it can't be lower then a or aa.

Comment: @Liger86 we get that, but unsure why.

Comment: I get "199 199 200 200" as last pairs when I run my code. While I do understand that that after 199 it will only draw 200, why does it draw 199 in a so often?

Comment: @Liger86 Do you *always* get that as the last pairs?

Comment: very often i get 198 198 199 199, or something similar in this extreme of specified range. Often times my two pairs (final pairs) come out to be in 175-200 range. Ran this almost 50 times, only once seen where a and aa were under 50.

Comment: Lotteries are not like that. Numbers are chosen at random without replacement with uniform distribution. There are no ordering constraints.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the randomness of the `Random` class, at least nothing that would affect your code.

Your way of picking lottery numbers is incorrect. The first number that you pick gets a correct distribution in itself, but then you pick another number to be higher than the first, which will favour higher numbers in the range.

Also, when the first number is high, it's more likely to guess the second number as there is a smaller variation. In your guesses you will see considerably more hits in the higher numbers.

Other than that it looks all right. Determining how often you could guess a number doesn't have any linear distribution. You would very seldom get a right guess very early, and you would very seldom go for very long without ever getting it right. It's normal that you see a concentration around a specific number of guesses.

Comment: Im basing my random numbers in a similar way to megamillions, where only the final 6th ball gets completely new random value, but for example second number is always bigger then 1st number, that's where the confusion might be...

Comment: But I don't understand why I almost never get numbers in 100 and under range, or am I being redundant asking this? I'm confused a bit.

Comment: @Liger86: They sort the numbers after picking them, that's why they come in order.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't doing what you think it's doing. First, neither `a` nor `b` will ever be 56, because [the upper limit is exclusive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx). Second  if `a` is 54, `b` will always be 55. So there's a 1 in 56 chance that `a` and `b` are 54 and 55 respectively, but there should only be a 1 in 3,136 chance of that.

Update: This answer applies to a previous version of the question. Once things stabilize, I'll update it with the answer to whatever the final question works out to be.

Comment: Well, in my code I almost never get two pairs under value of 100.

Comment: With the new code, you should get `a` and `b` both under 100 about 1 out of 4 times.

Comment: I ran the program just now about 15 times and all those times final pairs were over 100, need screenshots?

Comment: Did you change the code again?! `b = x.Next(a + 1, 200);` Shouldn't that be `b = x.Next(1, 200);`?!

Comment: No, because I want to make sure that b is never smaller than a

Comment: So if `b` is smaller than `a`, swap them. But what you're doing is changing the distribution.

Comment: I suppose you cannot swap them if `a` is "announced" when we get it...like they do in the lotteries...

Comment: If you want to do it like they do in lotteries, then do it like they do in lotteries. Create some number of 'balls', pick one randomly, and remove it. Then repeat. But they won't come out in order. By forcing the second one to be larger than the first, you're making higher numbers more likely, which borks the distribution. `1` only gets one chance. `30` gets two.